# Use a custom modal in ui router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I would like to have my own modal in root HTML, which can be called anytime from the child state.

For example, `index.html` is

```
<div ui-view="contacts"></div>  <--! load contact.html -->
<div ui-view="modal"></div>
```

then, `contacts.html`

```
<div> contact detail </div>
<button ng-click="openModal('confirmModal')"> delete it ? </button>
```

When clicking the button, I would like, for example, to prompt a modal and confirm the action. I'd like to make use of the template system provided by `ui-router`, so I can separate the different view for the different modal (probably there is different state for each).

The routing table I designed is as follows,

```
app.config(['$stateProvider',function(s) {
  s.state('index',{
     views : {
       contacts : {
          templateUrl : "views/contacts.html"
       }
     }
  ).state('openConfirmModal',{
     views : {
       modal : {
          templateUrl : "views/modal.confirm.html"
       }
     }
  }).state('openOtherModal',{
     //... loading other modal
  })
}
```

When going from state `index` to `openConfirmModal`, the `modal.confirm.html` should be loaded into `modal` view without destroying and refreshing the displaying `index` view, so that it will behave like a "modal".

But what `ui-router` actually does is to close or refresh the `index` view, when the state is changed.

I know some ideas about add the event listener for `$stateChangeStart`, so that it will not refreshing the `index` view when the event happen. But I don't know how to load the modal into the view within the event handler.

Comment: See the ui-router wiki. You'd have to make the modal state a child state, so that the parent does not get reloaded. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-open-a-dialogmodal-at-a-certain-state

Comment: I am trying to have my own modal, without the bootstrap ui, which looks like what [this blog](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2806-creating-a-simple-modal-system-in-angularjs.htm) describe. They are not using the `ui-router` to manage the view hierarchically, but just manually specify the ready DOM.

Comment: Thanks for you comment, I am wondering if there is a way to unify the modal system with the ui-router. It seems that all the existing solutions are ignoring the routing system, which means it needs another manual route inside the modal.